# Bad performance using VBO with OpenGL ES in Android

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, vbo

I'm making an **Android** app and I need to draw some shapes using **OpenGL ES**. I'm able to render them but I'm disappointed with performance. I updated the code to use **VBO** but I didn't notice any improvement. I want to render at **60 frames** per second (**16** ms per frame).

I have a test project where I render several triangles on the screen. When I render **1000** triangles it takes about **20 ms** per frame (depending on the device).

I want to keep the rendering under **10 ms** because I need the rest (**6 ms**) to perform other calculations (e.g. update positions, detect collisions, etc.).

Here is the code where I render a triangle:

https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/test/blob/master/src/com/testopengl/Polygon.java#L51-66

Here is the code where iterate over the triangles:

https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/test/blob/master/src/com/testopengl/MapRenderer.java#L117-139

(Change the value of **NUMBER_OF_TRIANGLES** to display more triangles)

For what I understand, the method **GLES20.glDrawArrays(...)** takes too much time if I need to call it **1000** times per frame (one per triangle).

Is there another way to render several polygons that doesn't take too much?

Notes:

- In the example all the triangles have a fixed position on the screen but in the real scenario they will move around
- In the example I assign a random color to each triangle but in the real scenario each of them will have a fixed color

Comment: Try to minimize your OpenGLES calls - i.e. call glDrawArrays once for 10000 triangles containing multiple polygons.

Comment: How can I minimize the amount of calls to glDrawArrays if all the polygons have different shapes and rendered in different positions and with different colors? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put your positions/colors/normals ... in One VBO object and Draw them in one call.

Comment: an example here would be helpful